# javascript function call for multiple controls

Tags: javascript, registerstartupscript

I have a javascript function which I am calling for multiple controls,but it seems to be calling for the first   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript only.

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "textCounter('" + txtCourseDesc.ClientID + "','" + txtRemDesc.ClientID + "', '2000')", true);
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "textCounter('" + txtReqCourseCode.ClientID + "','" + txtRemCode.ClientID + "', '90')", true);
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "textCounter('" + txtPReq.ClientID + "','" + txtPreqRem.ClientID + "', '1000')", true);
```

Please point out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use same key for one function with different parameters. Try this:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript2000", "textCounter('" + txtCourseDesc.ClientID + "','" + txtRemDesc.ClientID + "', '2000')", true);
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript90", "textCounter('" + txtReqCourseCode.ClientID + "','" + txtRemCode.ClientID + "', '90')", true);
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript1000", "textCounter('" + txtPReq.ClientID + "','" + txtPreqRem.ClientID + "', '1000')", true);
```